# how to insert array multidimensional javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some arrays and I want to insert dynamic multidimension array

```js
var multi = [];

var group = 'fruit';
var fruit_name = 'apple';

multi[group][fruit_name].push({'berbiji' : 'ya', 'panen' : '3tahun'});
```

why error like this "TypeError: multi[group] is undefined"

Comment: index can only integer in array

Comment: Well that's a hash and not array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to make array act like an object. If you want to make your code work, than you should write like:

```
var multi = {};
var group = 'fruit';
var fruit_name = 'apple';

multi[group] = {};
multi[group][fruit_name] = [];
multi[group][fruit_name].push({'berbiji' : 'ya', 'panen' : '3tahun'});
```

Comment: yes it is oonly example for my javascript project, iam adversity to solve this problem, and it's working!! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The names of the keys ('fruit' and 'apple') are not numbers so it is not a matrix (array of arrays) but a set of nested objects.

Nested Array (keys are numbers):

```
multiArray = [[
  {'berbiji' : 'ya', 'panen' : '3tahun'}]]
]]
multiArray[0][0].panen === '3tahun' // true
```

Nested Object (keys are strings):

```
multiObject = {
  fruit: {
    apple: {'berbiji' : 'ya', 'panen' : '3tahun'}
  }
}
multiArray[group][fruit_name].panen === '3tahun' // true
```

Either way, the nested object or array needs to be initiated before you can assign values to keys.

To follow your example:

```
var multi = {}
var group = 'fruit'
var fruit_name = 'apple';
multi[group] = {} // same as multi.fruit = {}
multi[group][fruit_name] = {'berbiji' : 'ya', 'panen' : '3tahun'}
multi.fruit.apple.panen === '3tahun' // true
```